# Load image from sd card to webview in Android JellyBean OS

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview

I have html content and images to load in webview in jelly bean OS. images are taken from sd card.

Here are the content:

```html
 <html>
      <head>
      <title>Test Name</title>
      </head>
      <body>
      <p><font color="#003399"   size="2">
      <center>
      <a href="file://storage/sdcard0/images/img.jpg" target="_blank" >
      <img src="file://storage/sdcard0/images/img.jpg" />
      </a>
      </center>
      </p>
      </font> Contetnt Goes Here 
      </body>
  </html>
```

```java
myWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("",webcontent, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Its working in ICS OS but does not load into jelly bean OS web view.

Thanks in advance